# How do I enable AddressSanitizer (Asan) on PlatformIo (pio)?

Tags: c++, googletest, address-sanitizer, platformio

I'm new to C++ but have experience with Java. I'm writing an Arduino project which I'm testing using gtest. I'd like these tests to fail if I've made a mistake with memory management. I've found that AddressSanitizer and Valgrind are candidates for detecting leaks at runtime. It looks like the PlatformIo 'check' capability isn't as comprehensive. Since I run my unit tests repeatedly (currently a run takes ~5 seconds) I'm leaning towards AddressSanitizer for my memory validation.

I did some searches on Google and didn't find any tutorials. It could be this is so basic everyone knows how to do it, or that PIO doesn't need special configuration. Either way, I'm hoping someone has done this and can share a reference or explanation of the basic process. Thanks!

**Update:**
I got some guidance that it makes sense to test the general functionality before the target specific functionality. That makes tons of sense. For me this translates to having an entry in my Platform.ini like this:

```
[env]
test_framework = googletest

[env:native]
platform = native
build_src_filter = ...
```

`build_src_filter` excludes my Arduino specific code. I'm hoping to find a way to catch leaks in my native configuration. Ideally I can do this within the Platform.io experience.

Comment: "LeakSanitizer is a memory leak detector which is integrated into AddressSanitizer. The tool is supported on x86_64 Linux and OS X."  Arduino is not x86_64 Linux nor macOS (*fka* OS X).

Comment: When possible, do as much of the debugging work as you can on a target that is easy to debug to knock out the non-target-specific stuff before you move the development to the embedded platform.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! I agree that I'm unlikely to be able to do this well on my Arduino target. Do you have advice on how to hook a leak detector into Platform.io for native C++ code? I've clarified my question.